# UWP Как загрузить изображение на сервер?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Необходимы выгружать изображения на сервер, и принимать их там с помощью `PHP` кода.
Для удобной обработки фотографий необходимо наделить эту посылку с фотографией каким либо заголовком. Думаю, что удобнее всего это сделать через `HttpClient`, но до конца разобраться и довести до рабочего варианта пока не получилось. Может кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, поделитесь опытом пожалуйста)

Comment: Вам непонятно как отправлять POST запросы с HttpClient или файл как-то некорректно загружается?

Comment: @Mr.Modest Ну в пост запросах запросах я тоже не оч силен, но обычный пост, вроде, осилил. А вот пост с картинкой, заголовком и обработать ее на сервере не оч получается

Comment: вот примеры моих запросов. Может вам поможет чем-то: https://github.com/MrModest/ShikiApiLib/blob/master/ShikiApiLib/ApiQuery.cs